# Certificate pinning with Microsoft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

We have developed an android mobile application where we are interacting with microsoft graph api. We have to add certificate pinning to avoid man in the middle  attacks. To implement this we will need to hardcode the public key in the app, but Microsoft graph apis keeps on changing the public key.

How can we implement certificate pinning and how can we prevent man in middle attacks?

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Certificate Transparency](https://medium.com/babylon-engineering/android-security-certificate-transparency-601c18157c44) which provides an open framework for monitoring and auditing SSL certificates in nearly real time. Specifically, Certificate Transparency makes it possible to detect SSL certificates that have been mistakenly issued by a certificate authority or maliciously acquired from an otherwise unimpeachable certificate authority. It also makes it possible to identify certificate authorities that have gone rogue and are maliciously issuing certificates.

Please take a look to [Certificate Transparency for Android](https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-android).

Comment: Hi I am seeing there is only one link for this. Also there is nothing like certificate transparency in android developer website. Can you please provide more link and more details about that.

Comment: @Duke please take a look to this [README](https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-android/blob/main/sampleapp/README.md).